# Use Omnicontacts gem for getting yahoo contacts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omnicontacts-gem

I am using **omnicontacts gem** for retrieving mail contacts. I am able to use it for gmail but for yahoo I always get an error :-

"**Custom port is not allowed or the host is not registered with this consumer key**".

I am not specifying any custom port in my callback url. Also I have verified the domain in yahoo app but still getting the same error. Help please.
I went through this link as well

[OmniContacts gem always fail on with my yahoo contacts importes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215434/omnicontacts-gem-always-fail-on-with-my-yahoo-contacts-importes)

My callback url is

```
http://www.domain-name/callback
```

where domain-name is my domain name.

and my routes file is as follows

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    match "/contacts/:importer/callback" => "main#index", :via => [:get]
    match "/oauth2callback" => "main#contact", :via => [:get]
    match "/callback" => "main#contact", :via => [:get]
    root 'main#index'

end
```

My controller code is as follows :-

```
class MainController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end

    def contact
      @contacts = request.env['omnicontacts.contacts']
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
      end
    end

end
```

Comment: Have you registered `http://www.domain-name/` as host at yahoo ?, Its clearly saying `host is not registered with this consumer key`

Comment: Is your callback correctly defined, I see `match "/contacts/:importer/callback" => "main#index", :via => [:get]`, but you are reading contacts in `main#contact`, Why not write `"/contacts/:importer/callback" => "main#contact", :via => [:get]`

Comment: I did not get an option of specifying a host at yahoo when I registered the app .. These are the options I got when I registered the app..

Application Name, Application TypeWeb Application, Description(Optional), Home Page URL(Optional), Callback Domain(Optional), API Permissions

Comment: I am also using the correct Client id and client secret.

Comment: Have you added Home Page URL(Optional), Callback Domain(Optional) though its optional?, and make sure your reading client_id and secret from correct environment if you are using different keys for different environments, I have used this gem before I did get any error

Comment: I have added the optional parameters as well. But I need to ask one thing. Currently I am testing this app on test server so technically it does not have a domain name.. Can this be a possibility ? I cannot test it directly on live. So if that is the case then I will need to either check the app on heroku.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76356/discussion-between-pramod-shinde-and-anirudh-rautela).

Answer (score 1):

See if following links helps

[OmniContacts gem always fail on with my yahoo contacts importes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215434/omnicontacts-gem-always-fail-on-with-my-yahoo-contacts-importes)

https://developer.yahoo.com/forum/OAuth-General-Discussion-YDN-SDKs/Custom-port-is-not-allowed-or/1270167545000-b347dc6e-08c1-3fcc-b3cd-d6ff0fb6d734/